# Setting a release as iPad-only on the Appstore

Tags: xcode, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect

I would like to release on iPad only. I have checked only iPad under Deployment Info in XCode, but I am still being asked to upload game screenshots to AppStore Connect for iPhone and iPad. It is also asking for both sets of icons in XCode.

Can I confirm that when the app is released, it will be for iPad only? Is there a way I can confirm this on the Appstore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you upload your binary file, App Store Connect will analyse the configuration. The iPad only flag will then be detected and you can remove your screenshots.
Simply ignore the ihone screenshots until you upload your binary.