# Blazor Hybrid MAUI iOS iPad/Tablet Only

Tags: ios, ipad, blazor, blazor-webassembly, maui-blazor

How can I configure my Blazor MAUI Hybrid App .csproj to set that the app is designed for iPad/Tablet only (and not iPhone and phones etc)? I saw in this question it is possible: [Setting a release as iPad-only on the Appstore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64412676/setting-a-release-as-ipad-only-on-the-appstore) but I don't know how to configure my app to set this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set it in Info.plist.

In Visual Studio for Mac, there is a Target Device family, 1 is for iphone and 2 is for ipad. So just leave 2.

In Visual Studio, choose iPad for Devices.

For more info, you could refer to [Compiling for different devices in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/compiling-for-different-devices?tabs=macos) and [UIDeviceFamily](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW11)
.

Hope it works for you.